# Making multiple sync AJAX calls and showing the status

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a for loop in which I make an AJAX call with the key and append the results to a table. After each call, I trigger a progress bar. When I make async calls, it freezes after 5-6 calls and doesn't respond. If I make the calls sync, it works perfectly but this time I can't show the status on the progress bar as it freezes the page.

```
$("#btn-fetch").on("click", function() {
  var starts = $('#starts').val();
  var ends = $('#ends').val();
  var howmany = ends - start + 1;

  $('#progress-text').html('<strong>%0</strong>');
  $('#progress-status').css('width', '0%');
  var percent = 100 / howmany;
  var progress_status = 0;

  for (var i = start; i <= ends; i++) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'fetch.php',
      data: {
        id: i
      },
      type: "POST",
      //async: false,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#table-body").append(data);
        progress_status += percent;
        $('#progress-text').html('<strong>%' + progress_status.toFixed(2) + '</strong>');
        $('#progress-status').css('width', progress_status.toFixed(2) + '%'); -
      },
      error: function(err) {
        console.log(err) // Reject the promise and go to catch()
      }
    });
  }
})
```

Comment: I want it to make the calls one by one with seeing the progress.

Comment: one way, since `$.ajax` returns a promise, would be to use `async`/`await` .... i.e. `("click", async function(){` ... and `await $.ajax({`

Comment: Provide more specific debugging details regarding asynchronous requests than just *"it freezes"*. How many requests are there? Is your log being called for each one? Any errors thrown ? etc.

Comment: Browsers have a limit on the number of concurrent requests it will make to a server, usually around 4. But that shouldn't cause it to freeze, since it will just queue the requests and start a new one when a previous one completes.

Comment: Actually the answer from @Jaromanda X solved it perfectly. I found out that the freezing is caused by my backend code.